# Convention to define global const map

Tags: c, dictionary, enums, constants, c-preprocessor

Currently I do following:

**parser.h**

```
typedef enum {
    FIN = 0x80,
    RSV1 = 0x40
} WS_FLAGS;
```

**parser.c**

```
int main() {
    return WS_FLAGS.FIN;
}
```

what is the convention to define a global constant map?

I for example would prefer something like this:

```
int main() {
    return WS_FIN;
}
```

Bodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `FIN` is not defined as a local definition of `WS_FLAGS`. It is different from other languages like C#.

I don't know if it is a convension, but since you cannot declare namespaces in C, it usually prepend my enum declarations with some name that reminds of the enum name :

```
typedef enum {
    WS_FLAG_FIN = 0x80,
    WS_FLAG_RSV1 = 0x40
} WS_FLAGS;
```

or

```
typedef enum {
    WS_FIN = 0x80,
    WS_RSV1 = 0x40
} WS_FLAGS;
```

... so `WS_FIN` is unlikely to conflict with any other `something_FIN` declarations.

Then, in your main, you call I simply by :

```
int main()
{
    return WS_FLAG_FIN;
}
```

Comment: and how do you call WS_FLAG_FIN from another file

Comment: You have to incude `parser.h` in every C file where you use `WS_FLAGS`. And you call `WS_FLAG_FIN` just by writing `WS_FLAG_FIN`, not by `WS_FLAGS.WS_FLAG_FIN` or `WS_FLAGS.FIN`. It is not how C works.

Answer (score 0):

See the enumeration like `#define`.

If you write:

```
typedef enum {
    FIN = 0x80,
    RSV1 = 0x40
} WS_FLAGS;
```

Then you will have to write:

```
int   main()
{
   return FIN;
}
```

You can use the enumeration as a parameter like this:

```
int  foo(WS_FLAGS flag)
{
    return flag;
}

int  main()
{
    return foo(FIN); // return FIN
}
```